# Cannot create virtual environment inside a folder - jupyter error

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using Git Bash on Windows.
In order to create virtual environment for data science project I run:

```
pipenv install --python jupyter pandas jupyterlab notebook
```

and I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: failed to query C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\jupyter.exe with code 1 err: 'usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]\n               [--paths] [--json] [--debug]\n               
C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\virtualenv\\discovery\\py_info.py` not found.\n'

[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

I suspected that something was wrong with jupyter installation so I reinstalled it but error still appears. What may be the source of problem?

Comment: did your username includes space?

Comment: No, but it has "ł" in it. May that be a problem?

Comment: Yes that's the only problem bro